# Can't get JQuery plugin Slick (carousel) to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, http, slick.js

Here is my HTML header:

```
<!-- Bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Jquery slick plugin -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css"/>

<!-- My CSS -->
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is part of my body where I'm trying to display the carousel also where my javascript stuff is loaded:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="carousel">
                <div><img src="img/slide-1.jpg"></div>
                <div><img src="img/slide-2.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Jquery Slick plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"</script>

<!-- My JavaScript -->
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

<!-- My JQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

And finally my jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.carousel').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1
});
});
```

Been trying to figure this out for a while now so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: On the <!--Jquery Slick plugin --> you miss the closing > for the script tag

Answer (score 1):

one small miss is there in the code, the bootstarp.min.js will require jquery.

You need to include jquery before boot strap.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the plunker based on you

https://plnkr.co/edit/3NXz9Q69M3IxbTONg6n2?p=preview

Comment: Teach the OP how to figure this out.  Did you use the browser console? What did you see? How did you figure it out?

Comment: sure and thanks for suggestion @cale_b , the first step to debug is to look for any error in the developer console of the browser. In this case the error was well notified in the console.

Comment: So i moved the include for jquery before bootstrap, however its still not working. Where about should i include my own Jquery file? Straight after the jquery include?

cheers for the tip on using the console, completely forgot about that.
Now the console says : http://puu.sh/scy3W/d07b10259a.png

Comment: The custom script files should be added in the last. what is there in your custom Jquery file ??

Comment: There was something else in my JQuery file however i've now removed it. So the console isn't throwing any errors, but the carousel isn't showing instead the two images overlap each other: http://puu.sh/scyW7/96374a6d4c.jpg

Comment: It will be good if you can keep this code in script.js file itself.  whats the content in script.js right now? did you try to check the solution after shifting custom script files in at the end ?

Comment: I've now deleted the sepearte jquery file and put the carousel jquery code in the javascript file. For ease i've uploaded my code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/rL8wltlFwPftIFgEJJGf?p=preview

Comment: you have added the wrong script file in you plunker , the path should be 
<script src="script.js"></script>

Comment: here is your updated plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/3NXz9Q69M3IxbTONg6n2?p=preview

Comment: Okk in the plunker the file name was script.js only please check the updated plunker and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Finally got it working. Thank's for your help mate, sorry for being such a plunker. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that seems be working

https://jsfiddle.net/0p4fjskc/

You should include jquery fist !

```
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```